# How to show time difference of hours which are greater than 24 hours?

Tags: datetime, jasper-reports

I'm facing difficulties to show the time time difference in hours where hours are greater than 24. 
Right now I'm using the following in *iReport*

```java
(new SimpleDateFormat("dd':'HH':'mm':'ss")).format(new Date($V{avgDuration}.longValue()*1000))
```

where `$V{avgDuration}` is a variable in *jrxml* file which is the average time difference between two dates in *seconds*. Here it shows the *1 day 1 hour* but I want it to be *25 hour*. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem using `PeriodFormatterBuilder`. But for this, I need to use `joda-time` library.

In the expression editor of the `text box` in `jrxml` file, just wrote the following:

```
new org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .printZeroAlways()
        .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
        .appendHours().appendSeparator(":")
        .appendMinutes().appendSeparator(":")
        .appendSeconds()
        .toFormatter()
        .print(new org.joda.time.Period(
            $V{avgDuration}.longValue()*1000))
```